# How do I get the colourScale argument in networkD3 to accommodate multiple rows?

Tags: javascript, colors, bipartite, networkd3

I'm working with bipartite network data, trying to graph them in networkD3. The colourScale argument allows you to custom set node colors to some degree, but you either have to have a small number of categories, or you have to go through and manually color the nodes by hand. I'm trying to automate the process a little bit. Is there a way to make certain colors correspond with the same category of node, regardless of how many times it repeats, or the order in which it appears in your data frame, or is that capability not part of networkD3 at this time?

Comment: You'll be more likely to get a good response if you follow the advice in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. There are already 2 close votes on your question which is an indication that it needs substantial changes or improvements. Note that the advice in the above link is generally applicable to asking questions and getting help from the volunteer, open-source community, not only specific to StackOverflow.

Comment: I just edited the question to be more specific, so let me know if this is more manageable, or if there are existing resources for this question.

Comment: What function / which type of plot are you trying to make? Can you provide some reproducible example so that we have something to reference?

Comment: Hi CJ, sorry for the delay. My research team is moving away from R and toward Gephi, so I've been redirected to start learning that platform. If we return to R in the future, I will definitely try and make this more specific, but I have to put this on the shelf for now.